# CodeIgniter: Check if user is logged in for multiple pages without redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want use logged in check for all pages (registration, login, remind) without redirect in construct function.

But if I use die(), all pages not working. Which function can be replaced of die() ?

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->user->logged() == TRUE) {
        $data['message'] = 'You are already logged in';
        $this->load->view('error', $data);
        die(); // I don't want to use redirect('/error')
    }
}

public function registration() {
    ...
}

public function login() {
    ...
}

public function remind() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you ? I mean $this->load->view('You are already logged in'); ?

Comment: @mallix, sorry, this one - $this->load->view('error', $data) , but it's not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->user->logged() == TRUE) {
        $data['message'] = 'You are already logged in';
        $this->load->view('error', $data);

        $this->output->_display(); // <-- use this code for enable output with die()

        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will be executed on all pages as its in constructor. Rather you can check what to do if user not logged in:

```
if($this->user->logged() == FALSE) {
       redirect("/login");
    }
```

If user logged in, nothing need to be done, just assume user is logged in and implement your page. This will work fine.

If you want to do the same for other controllers, then use a base controller(like "MY_Controller") to have this login check. And extend this base controller to all child controllers. Will work fine.